# How to create a django-allauth regular and social account for testing purposes?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-allauth

I [managed to create a regular user](http://vpaste.net/xEjM1) as happens when signing in with [Django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth).

I've been trying to do the same for a social account (Github) but I am really struggling. I assume there must be people out here that had to make a social account for testing purposes. Could anyone show how they did that?

Also, if you know a better way to create a regular user this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The following snippet from the [django-allauth tests](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/tests.py) shows how to do this:

```
from allauth.account import app_settings as account_settings
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
from allauth.account.utils import user_email
from allauth.socialaccount.helpers import complete_social_login
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialApp, SocialAccount, SocialLogin
from allauth.utils import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.messages.middleware import MessageMiddleware
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
from django.test.utils import override_settings


class SocialAccountTests(TestCase):

    @override_settings(
        SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP=True,
        ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS=None,
        ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION=account_settings.EmailVerificationMethod.NONE  # noqa
    )
    def test_email_address_created(self):
        factory = RequestFactory()
        request = factory.get('/accounts/login/callback/')
        request.user = AnonymousUser()
        SessionMiddleware().process_request(request)
        MessageMiddleware().process_request(request)

        User = get_user_model()
        user = User()
        setattr(user, account_settings.USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD, 'test')
        setattr(user, account_settings.USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD, 'test@test.com')

        account = SocialAccount(user=user, provider='openid', uid='123')
        sociallogin = SocialLogin(account)
        complete_social_login(request, sociallogin)

        user = User.objects.get(
            **{account_settings.USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD: 'test'}
        )
        self.assertTrue(
            SocialAccount.objects.filter(user=user, uid=account.uid).exists()
        )
        self.assertTrue(
            EmailAddress.objects.filter(user=user,
                                        email=user_email(user)).exists()
        )
```

Comment: What if you want the username to be autogenerated from email?

Comment: Wow, this is so complex.